# How do I determine the number of subsets in this question?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am struggling to understand a H.W. problem (p. 50 Discrete Math, Goodaire, *et al.*).

> Let $n>3$ and $A =\{1,2,3,...,n\}.$ How many subsets of A contain $\{1,2\}$?

The answer is $2^{n-2}$.

I see that if I take $P(A)$ then it would include $\{1,2\}$ as a subset. However, the answer is implying that there is another set that contains $\{1,2\}$ and I am not seeing it. I am not sure if I am interpreting the question correctly.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand.  Lots of subsets contain $1$ and $2$.  There's $\{1,2\}$, $\{1,2,3\}$, $\{1,2,4\}$ and so on.

Comment: I think "contain" here is confusing. They mean $\{1,2\}\subseteq T,$ not $\{1,2\}\in T.$ But often (usually?), when we say "$Y$ contains $X,$" we mean "$X\in Y.$" Here, the context dictates $\subseteq,$ at least if the problem is in a counting question, rather than a question trying to get check your understanding of sets.

Comment: That would be fine if the question said, "contains $1$ and $2.$" It didn't. @lulu That's definitely what they meant, but if you've just learned about sets, and you've just learned the difference between $\subseteq$ and $\in,$ it might be hard to determine from the question this is what they mean.

Comment: It's reasonable that the OP was confused and took it to mean $\{1,2\}\in S$ but it's also reasonable that such an interpretation would never occur to us to think it could possibly mean anything other than $\{1,2\}$.  It's bad communication all around but no-one's fault.... anyhoo... the mean how many sets contain bot $1$ and $2$.  For example $S=\{1,2, 5,6, 13\}$ would be such a set as $1,2\in S$.  ... now can the OP see why there would be $2^{n-2}$ such sets?

Comment: @fleablood I think I got it now. So $2^{n-2}$ is implying that there are only 2 subsets that doesn't contain {1,2}?

Comment: No... I don't think you have it.  The sets you want *must* have $1$ and must have $2$.  You have *NO* choice for those elements.  They *must* be in whatever set you try to construct.  You have $n-2$ other elements.  For each of those elements you have two choices.  Either you put it in your set, or you leave it out of your set.  So for those $n-2$ elements there are $2^{n-2}$ possible outcomes and each outcome yields a distinct set.

Comment: The number of sets that *don't* contain either $1$ nor $2$ is *also* $2^{n-2}$ for the exact same reason.

Comment: Basically if there are $k$ elements that may or may not be in a set then there are $2^k$ possible sets as there are $2$ choice for each unfixed element.  That is regardless of the number elements that *must* be in all sets, and regardless of the number of elements that are *forbidden* to be in any sets.

Comment: Another way you can look at it is if $1,2 \in S$ then $S = \{1,2\} \cup T$ there $T \subset \{3,4,5,6,.....,n\}$.    So the number of sets in $P(A)$ that include both $1$ and $2$ would be equal to the number of sets in $P(\{3,4,....,n\})$ (with which we just union them to $\{1,2\}$).  And as $|\{3,4,....n\}| = n-2$ then $|P(\{3,4,....,n\})| =2^{n-2}$.